# regular expression for shortest match in Python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7. The current code returns `hello }{(2) world`. If I only want the shortest match, in this case `hello`, what is the solution in Python 2.7?

```
import re

content = '{(1) hello }{(2) world}'
reg = '{\(1\)(.*)}'
results = re.findall(reg, content)
print results[0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the wildcard match [*non-greedy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions):

```
>>> reg = r'{\(1\)(.*?)}'
# this ? is important^
>>> results = re.findall(reg, content)
>>> print results[0]
 hello
```

Comment: Nice, thanks alecxe. Will mark your reply as answer in a few mins. Vote up first. :)

Comment: Mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation negated character class will also help you.

```
reg = r'{\(1\)([^}]*)}'

results = re.findall(reg, content)

print results[0]
```